# Added a ACF field to custom page and want the results to show as a column in admin

Tags: posts, customization, pages

A developer made a custom page for our wordpress site and I've added a custom field at the top titled Serial Number.

[image]

I want to add this field as a column to the admin page between Date Registered and Status. This field should say Yes if the radio button has been selected. Left blank if it has been unchecked.

[image]

This is the code that was created for that page:

```
// Add columns to the serials admin grid
```

function sha_wreg_columns_head( $defaults ) {
    global $sha_wreg_prefix;
    unset( $defaults['date'] );
    $defaults[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system_name' ] = __('System Name', 'sha-wreg' );
    $defaults[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'generation_date'] = __('Date Generated', 'sha-wreg' );
    $defaults[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'register_date' ] = __('Date Registered', 'sha-wreg' );
    $defaults[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status' ] = __('Status', 'sha-wreg' );
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_' . $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_posts_columns', 'sha_wreg_columns_head');

// Make date columns sortable
function sha_wreg_add_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    global $sha_wreg_prefix;

```
$columns[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'generation_date' ] = 'generation_date';
$columns[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'register_date' ] = 'register_date';

return $columns;
```

}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-' . $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_sortable_columns', 'sha_wreg_add_sortable_columns' );

// Add date sorting to query
function sha_wreg_add_orderby_to_query( $query ) {
    global $sha_wreg_prefix;

```
if ( ! is_admin() )
    return;

$orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

if ( 'generation_date' == $orderby ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
}

if ( 'register_date' == $orderby ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', $sha_wreg_prefix . 'register_date' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
}
```

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sha_wreg_add_orderby_to_query' );

// Add columns to the PDFS admin grid
function sha_wreg_pdfs_columns_head( $defaults ) {
    unset( $defaults['date'] );
    $defaults['title'] = __('System', 'sha-wreg' );
    $defaults['pdf'] = __('PDF User Manual', 'sha-wreg' );
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_' . $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_pdfs_posts_columns', 'sha_wreg_pdfs_columns_head');

// Add column contents
function sha_wreg_columns_content( $column_name, $post_ID ) {
    global $sha_wreg_prefix;
    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_ID );

```
if ($column_name == $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system_name' ) {
    if ( !empty( $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ][0] ) ) {
        $system_data = unserialize( $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ][0] );
        echo $system_data['name'];
    }
}

if ($column_name == $sha_wreg_prefix . 'register_date' ) {
    if ( !empty( $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'register_date' ][0] ) ) {
        echo date( 'd/m/Y', (int)$post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'register_date' ][0] );
    }
}

if ($column_name == $sha_wreg_prefix . 'generation_date' ) {
    echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime( get_the_time('Y-m-d', $post_ID ) ) );
}

if ( $column_name == $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status' ) {
    if ( !empty( $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status' ][0] ) ) {
        echo $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status' ][0];
    }
}

if ( $column_name == 'pdf' ) {
    if ( !empty( $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ][0] ) ) {
        echo $post_meta[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ][0];
    }
}
```

}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'sha_wreg_columns_content', 10, 2);

// Add allocation fields to post type form
function sha_wreg_add_allocation_metabox( $item_data ) {

```
global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_plugin_dir;

// Get all existing serials
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_pdfs',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
);

$systems = array(
    ''  => 'Select System'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $systems[ get_the_ID() ] = trim( get_the_title() );
    }
}

$current_system = get_post_meta( $item_data->ID, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', true );

require_once $sha_wreg_plugin_dir . 'admin/templates/allocation_metabox.php';
```

}

// Add file field to PDFS to post type form
function sha_wreg_add_file_metabox( $item_data ) {

```
global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_plugin_dir;

$pdf_file = get_post_meta( $item_data->ID, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file', true );

require_once $sha_wreg_plugin_dir . 'admin/templates/pdf_file_metabox.php';
```

}

// Add details to post type form
function sha_wreg_add_details_metabox( $item_data ) {

```
global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_plugin_dir;

$predefined_details = array(
    'tank_capacity'     => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'System Tank Capacity', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'extra_opt1'        => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Optional Extra 1', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'extra_opt2'        => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Optional Extra 2', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'extra_opt3'        => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Optional Extra 3', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'date_manufactured' => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Date Manufactured', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'date_fitted'       => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Date Fitted', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'distributor'       => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Distributor', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    ),
    'other_info'        => array(
        'name'          =>  __( 'Other Information', 'sha-wreg'),
        'value'         =>  ''
    )
);

$details = unserialize( get_post_meta( $item_data->ID, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data', true ) );
if ( count( $details ) > 0 ) {
    $details = array_merge( $predefined_details, $details );
} else {
    $details = $predefined_details;
}

$extra_details_keys = array();

foreach ( $details as $k => $detail ) {
    if ( !in_array( $k, array_keys( $predefined_details ) ) ) {
        $extra_details_keys[] = $k;
    }
}

require_once $sha_wreg_plugin_dir . 'admin/templates/details_metabox.php';
```

}

// Add checkboxes to post type form
function sha_wreg_add_checkboxes_metabox( $item_data ) {

```
global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_plugin_dir;

$checkboxes = unserialize( get_post_meta( $item_data->ID, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data', true ) );

require_once $sha_wreg_plugin_dir . 'admin/templates/checkboxes_metabox.php';
```

}

// Add user details to post type form
function sha_wreg_add_user_metabox ( $item_data ) {
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_plugin_dir;

```
$user_details = get_post_meta( $item_data->ID, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'user', true );
$key_mapping = array(
    'name' => 'User Name',
    'surname' => 'User Surname',
    'address' => 'User Address',
    'town' => 'User Town',
    'postcode' => 'User Postcode',
    'country' => 'User Coutry',
    'email' => 'User Email',
    'phone' => 'User phone',
    'id' => 'User ID'
);

require_once $sha_wreg_plugin_dir . 'admin/templates/user_metabox.php';
```

}

// Show meta boxes
function sha_wreg_add_meta_fields() {

```
global $sha_wreg_module_slug;

add_meta_box(
    'sha-wreg-file-metbox',
    __( 'PDF file', 'sha-wreg' ),
    'sha_wreg_add_file_metabox',
    $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_pdfs',
    'normal',
    'high'
);

add_meta_box(
    'sha-wreg-checkboxes-metbox',
    __( 'System checkboxes', 'sha-wreg' ),
    'sha_wreg_add_checkboxes_metabox',
    $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_pdfs',
    'normal',
    'high'
);  


add_meta_box(
    'sha-wreg-allocation-metbox',
    __( 'System Allocation', 'sha-wreg' ),
    'sha_wreg_add_allocation_metabox',
    $sha_wreg_module_slug,
    'normal',
    'high'
);

add_meta_box(
    'sha-wreg-details-metbox',
    __( 'System details', 'sha-wreg' ),
    'sha_wreg_add_details_metabox',
    $sha_wreg_module_slug,
    'normal',
    'high'
);  

add_meta_box(
    'sha-wreg-user-metbox',
    __( 'User Data', 'sha-wreg' ),
    'sha_wreg_add_user_metabox',
    $sha_wreg_module_slug,
    'normal',
    'high'
);
```

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sha_wreg_add_meta_fields' );

// Add enctype to form to allow download images
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'sha_wreg_add_post_enctype');

function sha_wreg_add_post_enctype() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}

// Add Registered|Allocated quick filters
add_filter( 'views_edit-' . $sha_wreg_module_slug, 'sha_wreg_add_quick_filters');
function sha_wreg_add_quick_filters( $views ){
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix;

```
$registered = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'     => $sha_wreg_module_slug,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'quick_filter'  => true,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'       => $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status',
                'value'     => 'Registered',
                'compare'   => '='
            )
        )
    )
);
$registerd_total = $registered->found_posts;

$allocated = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'     => $sha_wreg_module_slug,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'quick_filter'  => true,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'       => $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status',
                'value'     => 'Allocated',
                'compare'   => '='
            )
        )
    )
);
$allocated_total = $allocated->found_posts;

// Remove Published and Mine quick filters
unset( $views['publish'] );
unset( $views['mine'] );
//unset( $views['trash'] );

$registered_css = ( $_GET['filter'] == 'registered' ) ? ' class="current"' : '';
$views['registered'] = sprintf(
    "<a href='edit.php?filter=registered&post_type=%s'%s>%s</a>",
    $sha_wreg_module_slug,
    $registered_css,
    sprintf(
        __( 'Registered (%d)', 'sha-wreg' ),
        $registerd_total
    )
);

$registered_css = ( $_GET['filter'] == 'allocated' ) ? ' class="current"' : '';
$views['allocated'] = sprintf(
    "<a href='edit.php?filter=allocated&post_type=%s'%s>%s</a>",
    $sha_wreg_module_slug,
    $registered_css,
    sprintf(
        __( 'Allocated (%d)', 'sha-wreg' ),
        $allocated_total
    )
);

return $views;
```

}

// Add filter var to query
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'sha_wreg_query_vars' );
function sha_wreg_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'filter';

```
return $vars;
```

}

// Add Registered|Allocated filters to query
add_filter( 'request', 'sha_wreg_add_meta_query_to_quick_filter' );
function sha_wreg_add_meta_query_to_quick_filter( $vars ) {
    global $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_module_slug;

```
// Skip, if not a correct post_type
if ( $vars['post_type'] != $sha_wreg_module_slug) {
    return $vars;
}

switch ( $vars['filter'] ) {
    case 'allocated':
        $vars = array_merge( $vars,
            array(
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status',
                        'value'     => 'Allocated',
                        'compare'   => '='
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    break;

    case 'registered':
        $vars = array_merge( $vars,
            array(
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    array(
                        'key'       => $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status',
                        'value'     => 'Registered',
                        'compare'   => '='
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    break;
}

return $vars;
```

}

// Prevent add serial with the same number
function sha_wreg_prevent_serial_duplication( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug;
    if ( ( $postarr['post_type'] == $sha_wreg_module_slug ) && ( !in_array( $postarr['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'auto-draft' ) ) ) && ( isset( $_POST['post_title'] ) ) ) {

```
    // Search for the card with same number and publish status
    $same_number = get_page_by_title( trim( $_POST['post_title'] ), ARRAY_A, $sha_wreg_module_slug );
    if ( isset( $same_number['post_status'] ) && ( $same_number['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['post_ID'] != $same_number['ID'] ) ) {
        // Register notice
        $_SESSION[ $sha_wreg_module_slug ] = __( 'This serial is already exist', 'sha-wreg' );
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'sha_wreg_prevent_serial_duplication', PHP_INT_MAX -1, 2 );

// Show admin notice
function sha_wreg_replace_admin_messages( $messages ) {
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug;

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $screen->id == $sha_wreg_module_slug ) {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION[ $sha_wreg_module_slug ] ) ) {
        $messages['post'][6] = $_SESSION[ $sha_wreg_module_slug ];
        unset( $_SESSION[ $sha_wreg_module_slug ] );
    }
}
return $messages;
```

}
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'sha_wreg_replace_admin_messages', 10, 1 );

// Save/update meta fields
add_action( 'save_post', 'sha_wreg_save_update', 10, 2 );

function sha_wreg_save_update( $item_id, $item_data ) {
    global $sha_wreg_module_slug, $sha_wreg_prefix, $sha_wreg_uploads_dir;

```
switch ( $item_data->post_type ) {

    case $sha_wreg_module_slug:
        // Update systems
        if ( isset( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ] ) ) {
            //Change status to allocating
            $system_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', true );
            $system_name = get_post( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ] )->post_title;
            $system_object = array(
                'id'    => (int)$_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system' ],
                'name'  => $system_name
            );

            if ( empty( $system_data ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', 'Allocated' );
            }
            update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', $system_object );
        }

        //Remove empty rows
        foreach ( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ] as $k => $v ) {
            if ( empty( $v['name'] ) || ( empty( $v['name'] ) && empty( $v['value'] ) ) ) {
                unset( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ][ $k ] );
            }
        }

        // Update details
        $detail_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data', true );
        $detail_data = unserialize( $detail_data );
        if ( $detail_data !== $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ] ) {
            update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data', serialize( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'detail_data' ] ) );
        }

    break;

    case $sha_wreg_module_slug . '_pdfs':
        // Update PDF
        if ( isset( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ] ) && $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {
            $oldfile = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file', true );
            $uploadfile = sprintf('%s/%s', $sha_wreg_uploads_dir,  $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ]['name'] );

            //Copy PDF
            if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file' ]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'pdf_file', basename( $uploadfile ) );
            }

            //Remove old PDF
            if ( isset( $oldfile ) && !empty( $oldfile ) ) {
                if ( file_exists( sprintf( '%s/%s', $sha_wreg_uploads_dir, basename( $oldfile ) ) ) ) {
                    unlink( sprintf( '%s/%s', $sha_wreg_uploads_dir, basename( $oldfile ) ) );
                }
            }
        }

        // Update checkboxes
        $checkbox_data = get_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data', true );
        $checkbox_data = unserialize( $detail_data );
        if ( $checkbox_data !== $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data' ] ) {
            update_post_meta( $item_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data', serialize( $_POST[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'checkbox_data' ] ) );
        }

    break;
}
```

}

Comment: I can't even read that question. We cannot code for you here but help. If you want to **DO** something then you should  **TRY** or **Hire** the one who can do.

Comment: Please clean up the code you've provided and only include the part where you're trying to add the custom column, not where you're adding meta boxes.